# Getting communication between a PN532 RFID reader powered by arduino UNO using matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino, rfid

I am trying to up a read and write mode on my PN532 RFID reader powered by Arduino UNO using Matlab code. I am totally new at this. I have coded something out however it is not displaying the information that my RFID reader is reading from the tag.

```
clear all; clc; close all;
s = serial('COM3');
set(s,'BaudRate', 115200);
set(s,'DataBits', 7);

set(s,'StopBits', 1);
fopen(s);
s.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';
readasync(s);

data = fscanf(s, '%x');
char=(dec2bin(data));
sprintf('Read data is %x', char);
```

The data that i got was 'ypyA r d u i n o S e r v e r   I O   L i b r a r y w'. 
I have made changes and trial and error however it is not making it any better. Hope anyone can help me with this. The information that my tag is sending will be in 8-bit hexadecimal values that i wish to convert and display in binary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you used a serial communication console directly before messing around with Matlab? Probably some test data would be cool as well and if you can provide it also the Arduino code you are using.

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasW. for your response. I have connected and successfully communicate the reader using the arduino code that was provided by the supplier through github. Below will be the link to the code. As its too long therefore i will prefer to send you the link. Upon running the board using arduino, i was able to read and write data that i want. However, i will like to implement this similar concept into matlab.  https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C/blob/master/examples/readMifare/readMifare.pde